# Is it possible to search within a question to find out that a specific user has posted an answer or a comment?

Tags: feature-request, support

Maybe it's better to say, how is it possible to determine that a special person has dealt with a question that has so many answers and comments?

For example, I found this [interesting question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/31104/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion) in which many people have cooperated to provide their opinions, but I want to know whether Mr. Eric Lippert also has provided any ideas (in form of comment or answer) about that or not.

At present, the only thing that comes to mind is to see all of the pages that related to the question and try to search for `eric` through Internet Explorer.  Of course, that's totally tedious, is there a better solution?

**in a nutshell :How can we see if a specific user has posted an answer or a comment to a specific question ?**

Comment: Are you asking, "How can we see if a specific user has posted an answer to a specific question?"

Comment: Yes exactly I mean That ,excuse me for my poor english =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search using the `inquestion` and `user` filters.

```
inquestion:[this|questionId] user:[userid]
```

You can see a list of the advanced search features [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=).

Comment: I tried inquestion:[this] user:[22656] AND inquestion:this user:22656 AND inquestion:this "Jon Skeet" but unfortunately non of them works for me .am i missing something here?thanks

Comment: @siamak, 22656 is Jon Skeets StackOverflow user id. The question you're looking at is on Programmers.StackExchange. His user id there is 8958. So try `inquestion:this user:8958`

Comment: @siamak, with the `[]` it does appear a little misleading.  If you search: `inquestion:this user:167724` it will show your *question*.  In other words, you must include the *user-id* (**from the current site** as @Brandon notes), not the *username*.  Searching `inquestion:this user:siamak` will not return anything. Note also that the search will not find your comment.

Comment: @Brandon @ M.Tibbits The world Looks beautiful,thanks ,But as Tibbits mentioned in this way we couldnt search in comments , only we can search in ANSWERS ,is there an option that could help to find the comment of a specific user?and do u know a way for that?  and do u think it could be a good and possible suggestion for stackoverflow? thanks again

Comment: @Siamak, comments have a history of being treated as second class citizens. I believe it would be declined. As far as I know, there is no way to search comments within StackOverflow. From a question, using the browser find wont always work, as collapsed comments need to be retrieved from the server. You could go to the user's profile, activity tab, and filter by comments. You could then use your browsers search feature to find the question.

Comment: @Brandon,Thank u again , as you said comments are _second class citizens_ and it seems that ther is not a way to search a specific question for comments of a specific user .so we juct can see all comments of a user through Activity tab .[Not all comments of a user for a specific question .in fact there is not such filtering option].and i think this could be a good feature request for SO.